# Dynamic JavaFX buttons action

Tags: events, button, javafx, controller

I have problem with managing dynamically created buttons actions. Here is sample of my "main" class:

```
    public class Lexicon {
        public String word;
        public String translation;
        public int id;
        ...
    }
```

And now, we have some FXML which contains Label which is compared to Lexicon Object. And now, i want to make X amount of Buttons, and each of them should "remember" one id from the list of choosen Lexicons:

```
    Lexicon labelLexicon;
    List<Lexicon> buttonLexicon;
```

In the buttonLexicon we have few Lexicon objects, and one of them is for sure same as labelLexicon. The task is, every button on click should compare remembered Lexicon.id with labelLexicon.id if they are equal, we do it again(it will random spawn another list) if not - printout something.
I Tried a lot of times with lambda expresions, but it didn't work for me or i just messed it... tried also to  make another help class like:

```
public class ButtonPair {
    public Button button;
    public int pairId;

    public ButtonPair(Button button, int pairId){
       this.button = button;
       this.pairId = pairId;
    }
}
```

But it don't want take any not-final conditions or it pop-up other exceptions... Then I tried something like that:

```
private void buttonTest(int n){

    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        Button button = new Button();

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle (ActionEvent e){
                if (buttonLexicon.get(i).id == labelLexicon.id){
                   //do something
                }
            }
        });
        buttonList.add(button);
        hbboxx.getChildren().clear();
        hbboxx.getChildren().addAll(buttonList);
    }
}
```

But every time i try with new conditions it still calls that "i" it has be final one - but it can't be, because it is in the loop... .
Tried to search also in stack overflow for solution but i can't find any...
So, anyone know how to smugle that condition to every new created button action? :(

I would be grateful for help

Comment: So there are different instances with the same id? Otherwise you could simply check reference equality also consider accessing the `Lexicon` instance directly without using the index: `for (final Lexicon lexicon : buttonLexicon) {... if (lexicon.id == labelLexicon.id)...}`

Comment: thanks! that's it, I didn't think about foreach loop with current buttonLexicon list (omitting the fact, i didn't realize that final statement would work in this loop condition while it didn't work in normal for). And sorry if my qestion was duplicate - didn't find similar here :( Anyway, thanks for help :))